# Determining cardinal (compass) direction between points

Tags: sql-server-2008, geometry, geography

Is there a way to know in SQL Server 2008R2 if a point is at the south,east,etc...of   another point?

For example, I have an origin `point(lat1,lng1)` and I want to know where `point(lat2,lng2)` is located from that origin: north, west,etc...

I'm trying to construct a wind rose graph and this might be useful to me.

Comment: if the second point's longtitude is greater than the first point, the second point is more north, otherwise south if second point's longtitude is less than the first.
if the second point's lattitude is greater than the first point, the second point is more east, otherwise west if the second point's lattitude is less than the first.

Comment: This is not correct. As you move further north, your latitude, not your longitude, increases. Longitude measures east/west, latitude measures north/south. A point with a latitude of 44.810901, for instance, is further north than a latitude of 37.42227.

Answer (score 5):

I came up with a way of calculating the bearing using a fairly straightforward use of standard SQL functions.

The `ATAN` function does most of the real work; the two `CASE` statements are just special case corrections. 1 is the source and 2 is the destination.

```
atan(([Longitude2]-[Longitude1])/(10e-10+[Latitude2]-[Latitude1]))*360/pi()/2
+case when [Latitude2]<[Latitude1] then 180 else 0 end
+case when [Longitude2]<[Longitude1] and [Latitude2]>[Latitude1] then 360 else 0 end
```

Comment: Just one tip.  Under some circumstances, the number is correct, but negative.  I added the abs() function to the query and the results seem to be correct every time.

Answer (score 4):

In order to calculate the bearing between two coordinates while using the Geography type in SQL Server 2008 R2, you can use this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CalculateBearing] 
(
    @pointA as geography
    ,@pointB as geography
)

RETURNS decimal(18,12)

AS

    BEGIN

    -- Declare the return variable
    DECLARE @bearing decimal(18,12)

    -- Declare the local variables
    DECLARE @x decimal(18,12)
    DECLARE @y decimal(18,12)
    DECLARE @dLat decimal(18,12)
    DECLARE @dLong decimal(18,12)
    DECLARE @rLat1 decimal(18,12)
    DECLARE @rLat2 decimal(18,12)

    IF(@pointA.STIsEmpty() = 1 OR @pointB.STIsEmpty() = 1)
        set @bearing = null
    ELSE
        BEGIN

        -- Calculate delta between coordinates
        SET @dLat = RADIANS(@pointB.Lat - @pointA.Lat)
        SET @dLong = RADIANS(@pointB.Long - @pointA.Long)

        -- Calculate latitude as radians
        SET @rLat1 = RADIANS(@pointA.Lat)
        SET @rLat2 = RADIANS(@pointB.Lat)

        SET @y = SIN(@dLong)*COS(@rLat2)
        SET @x = COS(@rLat1)*SIN(@rLat2)-SIN(@rLat1)*COS(@rlat2)*COS(@dLong)

        IF (@x = 0 and @y = 0)
            SET @bearing = null
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @bearing = CAST((DEGREES(ATN2(@y,@x)) + 360) as decimal(18,12)) % 360
            END
    END

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @bearing

END

GO
```

And after this, you can use this function like this:

```
DECLARE @pointA as geography
DECLARE @pointB as geography

SET @pointA = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(3 45)', 4326)
SET @pointB = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(4 47)', 4326)

SELECT [dbo].[CalculateBearing](@pointA, @pointB)
```

**UPDATE**: Adding a schema

[image: Bearing explanation]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but i have to say that i don't know how to read..or understand the result, for these coords the function returns the number 18.795229754601, what does it mean?, thank you.

Comment: It gives the orientation to the north.
So it is the angle described by North - Point A - Point B (NAB), so if you use a modulo 90, you can determine wether the point B is located on the north, east, south or west side of the point A.

Answer (score 3):

This morning I had need for this functionality to provide the range and cardinal direction to users when searching for nearby orders in our system. I came to Nicolas's answer here and it got me most of the way there. I created a second function that uses Nicolas's to get myself an abbreviated cardinal direction (N, NE, E, etc) for my UI.

Using Nicolas's bearing calculation provided here combined with values from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Points_of_the_compass to determine ranges for each cardinal direction,

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CalculateCardinalDirection] 
(
    @pointA as geography
    ,@pointB as geography
)

RETURNS varchar(2)

AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @bearing decimal(18,12)
    -- Bearing calculation provided by http://stackoverflow.com/a/14781032/4142441
    SELECT @bearing = dbo.CalculateBearing(@pointA, @pointB)

    RETURN CASE WHEN @bearing BETWEEN 0 AND 22.5 THEN 'N'
                WHEN @bearing BETWEEN 22.5 AND 67.5 THEN 'NE'
                WHEN @bearing BETWEEN 67.5 AND 112.5 THEN 'E'
                WHEN @bearing BETWEEN 112.5 AND 157.5 THEN 'SE'
                WHEN @bearing BETWEEN 157.5 AND 202.5 THEN 'S'
                WHEN @bearing BETWEEN 202.5 AND 247.5 THEN 'SW'
                WHEN @bearing BETWEEN 247.5 AND 292.5 THEN 'W'
                WHEN @bearing BETWEEN 292.5 AND 337.5 THEN 'NW'
                ELSE 'N' -- Catches NULL bearings and the 337.5 to 360.0 range
           END
END
GO
```

Comment: Nice, that's useful! I will update on of my code to add a column in one project. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the points data type are "Geometry" (Like UTM Coordinate System), you may use the following formula:

```
DEGREES(ATAN((X2-X1)/(Y2-Y1)))
+case when Y2<Y1 then 180 else 0 end
+case when Y2>Y1 and X2<X1 then 360 else 0 end
```

Here is the schema for more clarification:

[image: The Azimuth of a line which connects two points]

Answer (score 0):

`X=X2-X1` and `Y=Y2-Y1.` A formula that gives the bearing clockwise from 0 (positive Y axis) to 360 degrees.

```
  f(X,Y)=180-90*(1+SIGN(Y))*(1-SIGN(X^2))-45*(2+SIGN(Y))*SIGN(X)-180/PI()*SIGN(Y*X)*ATAN((ABS(Y)-ABS(X))/(ABS(Y)+ABS(X)))
```