# Storing custom coordinates in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, geospatial, geography

I have a table in SQL Server database that has a 2 fields X, Y. These fields represent coordinates on a field (american football field). 0,0 (X,Y) is the starting point with the largest value and furthest away point being 145,90 (X,Y).

Each row in the table is a coordinate from the pitch.

I want to be able to measure the distance between different coordinates on the field (different rows in the database) eg. 3,9 to 15,20. I also want to be able to measure the angle between coordinates.

I looked the spatial types etc in SQL Server but its seems to me that is related to Latitude, Longitude.

Is there any way in SQL Server that can I set such up in SQL with a custom map to measure between custom points, angles etc?

Comment: The proportions of an American football field aren't the same as 145:90. Does that mean that a distance of 1 on your X-axis is different from a distance of 1 on your Y-axis? (i.e., are they using different units of measurement?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Geometry type.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895270.aspx

Here's some quick examples.

Use a derived column to create a Point:

```
CREATE TABLE #Test (
  X INT,
  Y INT,
  POINT AS GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText('POINT('+CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),X)+' '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),Y)+')',0 )
)

INSERT INTO #Test( X, Y) VALUES (3, 9),(15,20)
```

If you want to view your points in SSMS adding a buffer can make things easier to see:

```
SELECT *,POINT.STBuffer(5) Pt FROM #Test
```

Distance is simple (say from the origin):

```
SELECT X, Y, POINT.STDistance(GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText('POINT(0 0)',0)) DistFromOrigin FROM #Test

X           Y           DistFromOrigin
----------- ----------- ----------------------
3           9           9.48683298050514
15          20          25
```

Between any two points is just a matter of selecting the points and doing

```
Point1.STDistance(Point2)
```

And for angles, this function should work fine when changed to the `Geometry` type

[Determining cardinal (compass) direction between points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736464/determining-cardinal-compass-direction-between-points)

Answer (score 1):

Do you remember the Pythagorean Theorem from algebra class? http://betterexplained.com/articles/measure-any-distance-with-the-pythagorean-theorem/ That is what is used the measure the "long" side of a triangle which is what you are measuring here. You don't need anything special other some basic math for this. You know that the distance from (3, 9) to (15, 50) is 12. This is the distance side to side, or X. Then you also know the distance down field is 41 (50 - 9). To determine the distance between these point is simple X(2) + y(2) = c(2). So in this example it would be 12(2) + 41(2) = x(2).

Simplified this becomes 144 + 574 = x(2)

To solve you take the square root of 718. This would resolve to 26.795

If you wanted to store this value you could easily make a computed column that could calculate this for you.

--EDIT--

I don't remember the formula for calculating the angle of the hypotenuse off the top of my head but it should be easy to find on the internet.

Comment: Like in my comment above, it's not as straightforward for the angle. Arctan(p2.y/p2.x) would work if p1 was the origin..otherwise things get shifted.

Comment: Not sure I understand how it changes. The distance between point A and point B don't change based on the location on the field. Or maybe you are referring to the angle portion.

Comment: I was referring to the angle portion. It's actually kinda confusing. You need to have one column of points to serve as your anchor, if you want to have an unambiguous way of defining the angle.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a supplement to Sean Lange's answer about the distance, the angle part is a little more ambiguous. If p1 was at the origin, then you'd find the angle simply by writing `arctan(p2.y/p2.x)`. But if the two points aren't anchored, things can be a bit ambiguous.

To define the angle relative to the x-axis, you want to use `arctan(abs(p2.y-p1.y)/abs(p2.x-p1.x))`, if `p2.x > p1.x` and `p2.y > p1.y`. That is `p2` is more right-ward than `p1`, and `p2` lies above `p1`. This is illustrated in Case 1 below.

However, we could just have easily defined the angle to be the result from the `arctan` from the previous paragraph PLUS 180 degrees, as in Case 2 below! So the notion of angle is not as clear, unless you have a particular column of points you want to use as your anchor.

[image]

Okay, but let's suppose we DO have one anchor column of points, labelled by p1, then we can use the `arctan` formula with some fandangling. As in the four cases below, for Case 1 we just use the `arctan` formula from above. For Case 2 we have to add on 270 degrees (think unit circle). For case 3 we add on 180 degrees, and in case 4 we add on 90 degrees.

Just to show another possible way of defining the angle, if we have one column we see as important. 
[image]

Comment: Okay...I neglected the burger my wife made for me, which is now probably cold and dry, in creating these silly diagrams. I should probably go eat that and make love to her. But it was kinda fun to think this through. Arctan is a nasty function.